# non-www to www redirection on main directory HTML and sub directory WordPress site not working

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a HTML website running on the main domain `http://arabyouthsurvey.com` and I have added non-www to www redirection on it by adding some code on my ***.htaccess*** for the main directory. Now I have a WordPress blog inside subdirectory like `http://arabyouthsurvey.com/media-center`.

First of all, I need to redirect all non-www URLs including my blog should be redirected with www.

The issues I am facing are:

If I am adding redirection on main directory's .htaccess. It is redirecting the URLs only for HTML website but, It is blocking the web fonts on my blog.

This error I am facing in my blog after adding redirection on main .htaccess file

`Access to Font at 'http://www.arabyouthsurvey.com/assets/fonts/karbon-regular-webfont.woff2' from origin 'http://arabyouthsurvey.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://arabyouthsurvey.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

If I am adding redirection in my blog .htaccess file too. It is not working.

This is the code I am adding in my main directory .htaccess file

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://arabyouthsurvey.com/page404.html

# redirect non www to www
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Here is my WordPress .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteBase /media-center/

 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
 RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^ - [L]
 RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
 RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
 RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: what urls do you have in WP admin panel > Settings > General > WordPress Address (URL) ... and Site Address (URL) ...?

Comment: @Andra I am not having these two URL options in my general settings. Actually, I have multisite setup, maybe that's why.